# client rejecting server certificate

Tags: validation, ssl, https

I am new to HTTPS/SSL.
I need to write a HTTPS client which will reject all the connection by saying unknown CA . As I understand  (through wireshark capture) during SSL connection, first client will send the 'client hello' message. In reply to this server will send message with three record - 'server hello', certificate, 'server hello done'.

What I am trying to achieve here is when the server will send certificate, client should always reject it.

I am trying to achieve it with following code but no luck.

[How can I get LWP to validate SSL server certificates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74358/how-can-i-get-lwp-to-validate-ssl-server-certificates)

It's ok if solution is in some other language.

Comment: What platform/language are you targeting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to do the connection with no (or dummy) CA certificates known to the client. Have you tried setting [SSL_ca_path](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#SSL_ca_path) and [SSL_ca_file](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.02/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm#SSL_ca_file) to dummy values?

*Edit:*

If any language goes, why not try [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/)s [s_client](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/s_client.html)?

```
openssl s_client -connect www.stackoverflow.com:443
```

Comment: Does the SSL library you are using actually verify the CA? It might be accepting any certificate.

Comment: It looks to me that SSL library is not verifying the CA. I can pass any value to   SSL_ca_file and it's still working.